# MySQL insert combo from php var and other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to insert into my sql table a combination of php variables and 1 row data from another table.  ive found examples that are similar but none that have this combination.

`OTHERTABLE.liveDate` would be where i need the single record from, but i would need to add a condition such as `WHERE id='1'` from OTHERTABLE
`'$navid', '$loginid', '$total', '$where'` are not from OTHERTABLE

```
INSERT INTO myTable (`navid`,`loginid`, `pageDisplayNum`, `whereFrom`, `liveDate`) 
VALUES ('$navid', '$loginid', '$total', '$where', 'OTHERTABLE.liveDate')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO myTable (`navid`,`loginid`, `pageDisplayNum`, `whereFrom`, `liveDate`) 
select '$navid', '$loginid', '$total', '$where', OTHERTABLE.liveDate 
from OTHERTABLE
where OTHERTABLE.id='1'
```

Comment: +1 I did not know you can do this. I always inserted a foreign key. What are the pro/cons of the answer vs using a foreign key?

Comment: thank you for the response,  i've edited my question. '$navid', '$loginid', '$total', '$where' are not from OTHERTABLE